# Update multiple documents in MongoDB by altering object in array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have a simple application with registration/login and it is basically a coursera/udemy type, where the app lists specific courses and users can like them or enroll in them. I have been trying to make a mongodb function that updates a user in the database and since users can like the courses it has to update all courses too (courses have a field "usersLiked", which is an array and keep all user documents which have liked it).

The course structure is the following:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5977662564aac9f6c8d48884"),
    "title" : "Title",
    "lecturer" : "Lecturer",
    "length" : 30,
    "coverPhoto" : "Photo",
    "usersLiked": [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("597763e346a7a463cbb8f529"),
            "fullname" : "Name",
            "username" : "Username",
            "password" : "Hash",
            "city" : "City",
            "street" : "Street",
            "website" : "Website"
        }
    ],
    "lectures" : [ 
        {
            "title" : "Introduction",
            "number" : 1,
            "url" : "someURL"
        }
    ]
}
```

And the user structure:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("597763e346a7a463cbb8f529"),
    "fullname" : "Name",
    "username" : "Username",
    "password" : "Hash",
    "enrolledCourses" : [ 
        ...
            ]
        }
    ],
    "city" : "City",
    "street" : "Street",
    "website" : "Website"
}
```

So now I am calling this function when I want to change. It changes the userCollection but in the courseCollection it does nothing, while it should get all courses and if some of them have an object with username(the user's username) in the "usersLiked" array it should modify the user there too.

```
const updateUser = (username, details) => {
        usersCollection
            .update({
                username: username,
            }, {
                $set: {
                    fullname: details.fullname,
                    city: details.city,
                    street: details.street,
                    website: details.website,
                },
            });
        coursesCollection
            .updateMany(
                {
                    usersLiked: {
                        $elemMatch: {
                            username: username,
                        },
                    },
                },
                {
                    $set: {
                        'usersLiked.username': details.username,
                        'usersLiked.city': details.city,
                        'usersLiked.street': details.street,
                        'usersLiked.website': details.website,
                    },
                }
            );
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your match on the course update looks valid but you are trying to set values into an array and according to the [Mongo docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) you need to provide an array indexer or a  positional operator.

The following will allow the set command to operate on the **first** element within the `usersLiked` array which matches the given `username`.

```
coursesCollection.updateMany(
    {
        usersLiked: {
            $elemMatch: {
                username: username,
            },
        },
    },
    {
        $set: {
            'usersLiked.$.username': details.username,
            'usersLiked.$.city': details.city,
            'usersLiked.$.street': details.street,
            'usersLiked.$.website': details.website
        },
    }
)
```

You could also choose which element in the `usersLiked` array to update e.g. `usersLiked.1.username` but I suspect each course only has one element in `usersLiked` for a given `username` in which case using the `$` operator (which means: the first matching array element) should suffice.

Comment: But by doing this wont, I change all of the users who have liked that course. And that still doesnt work.

Comment: The set operation will only apply to the first element in the usersLiked array in the document(s) which match the $elemMatch clause. The $elemMatch focuses on a single user so the set operation will not change all of the users who have liked that course.

Comment: I see, but still that does not change the document in the database.

Comment: Before posting my answer I created documents matching those you supplied in your question and I ran the command I supplied and it successfully updated the usersLiked array. Could you perhaps run that command stand alone i.e. using a Mongo shell to prove that the match and set phases are successful.